# Extending an interface with another interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, xamarin.ios

Good day everyone,

I have a question about interfaces and how they extend/inherit from each other. The question has little to do with GPU-programming.

**The question:**

I have two interfaces: GPUImageView and GPUImageInput.

GPUImageView is defined: `interface GPUImageView : GPUImageInput { /*some code*/ }`

I have a function: `void AddTarget(GPUImageInput newTarget) {/*some code*/}`

When i pass in an instance of GPUImageView into AddTarget i get an error that it can't convert GPUImageView to GPUImageInput.

**Additional information:**

I am trying to bind the GPUImage library in Monotouch with btouch. I tried to port one of their examples (SimplePhotoFilter) as a test.

This resulted in

- Democode which i put in ViewDidLoad method.
- APIDefinitions.cs which    i filled with the necessary bindings.
- StructsAndEnums.cs which is    empty for the time being.

**Here is the code in APIDefinitions.cs**

```
namespace GPUImage
{
    [BaseType (typeof(UIView))]
    interface GPUImageView : GPUImageInput{
        [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
        IntPtr Constructor(RectangleF frame);

        [Export ("autoresizingMask")]
        UIViewAutoresizing AutoResizingMask { get; set;}

        [Export ("addSubView")]
        void AddSubView(UIView view);
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    [Model]
    interface AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{

    }

    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    [Model]
    interface AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{

    }

    [BaseType (typeof(GPUImageOutput))]
    interface GPUImageVideoCamera : AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{
    }   

    [BaseType (typeof(GPUImageVideoCamera))]
    interface GPUImageStillCamera{
        [Export ("outputImageOrientation")]
        UIInterfaceOrientation OutputImageOrientation { get; set;}

        [Export ("startCameraCapture")]
        void StartCameraCapture();      
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter))]
    interface GPUImageSketchFilter{ 
        [Export ("prepareForImageCapture")]
        void PrepareForImageCapture();
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(GPUImageTwoPassFilter))]
    interface GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter {
        [Export ("texelWidth")]
        float TexelWidth{ get; set;}

        [Export ("texelHeight")]
        float TexelHeight{ get; set;}
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(GPUImageFilter))]
    interface GPUImageTwoPassFilter {
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(GPUImageOutput))]
    interface GPUImageFilter : GPUImageInput{
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    [Model]
    interface  GPUImageInput{
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface  GPUImageOutput{
        [Export ("addTarget")]
        void AddTarget(GPUImageInput newTarget);
    }
}
```

**And this is the code in the viewController:**

```
GPUImage.GPUImageStillCamera stillCamera = new GPUImage.GPUImageStillCamera ();
stillCamera.OutputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
GPUImage.GPUImageFilter filter = (GPUImage.GPUImageSketchFilter)new GPUImage.GPUImageSketchFilter ();
((GPUImage.GPUImageSketchFilter)filter).TexelHeight = 1.0f / 1024.0f;
((GPUImage.GPUImageSketchFilter)filter).TexelWidth = 1.0f / 768.0f;
((GPUImage.GPUImageSketchFilter)filter).PrepareForImageCapture ();
stillCamera.AddTarget (filter);
GPUImage.GPUImageView filterView = (GPUImage.GPUImageView)this.View;
filter.AddTarget (filterView);
```

And these are the error messages i get: 
ImageProcessingLabViewController.cs(37,37): Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`GPUImage.GPUImageOutput' expression to type `GPUImage.GPUImageInput' (CS1503) (ImageProcessingLab)

ImageProcessingLabViewController.cs(32,32): Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`GPUImage.GPUImageView' expression to type `GPUImage.GPUImageInput' (CS1503) (ImageProcessingLab)

But as you can see, GPUImageFilter inherits/implements/extends GPUImageInput, which should allow me to use/cast GPUImageSketchFilter, GPUImageOutput and GPUImageView as GPUImageInput.

Clarification: The error occur when i try to call AddTarget which expects a GPUImageInput. I am giving it a GPUImageFilter which inherits from GPUImageOutput and implements GPUImageInput. GPUImageFilter should be castable to a GPUImageInput, but causes an error instead.

Grateful for any answer. 
Am i missing something?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Monotouch from Xamarin is C# and .net for iPhone.

Comment: To be clear, `GPUImageOutput` is a class, `GPUImageInput` is an Objective-C protocol. `-addTarget:` expects a generic (id) type that complies to the `GPUImageInput` protocol. `GPUImageView` is a UIView subclass that complies to the `GPUImageInput` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that particular framework, however, there are limited hardware options for implementation.

If the library used GPGPU (e.g. CUDA) buffers for images, there wouldn't be a separate definition for input and output images (perhaps there would be a separate definition for fast access read only images based on texture memory).

If the library uses the standard graphics pipeline, then the image can either be stored in a texture used as input for the pipe line, or in the PBuffer, used as output of the pipe line - two separate physical (or logical? - depends on specific hardware implementation) locations.

To transfer from one memory type to another a cast is not enough, you need to read the buffer and write it to a different allocated location.

The implementation of the framework may use the same base class for both, however, the implementations are probably not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not compilable C# code. It's the Obj-C binding definition. The btouch command line utility then generates real C# code and compiles into a library you can reference. In your example, the class in the compiled assembly is defined as

```
public class GPUImageView : UIView
{
}
```

and

```
public class GPUImageOutput : NSObject
{
}
```

Neither of which actually inherits from GPUImageInput, none of them are really interfaces. You can read this [guide](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs) for more information.